# .htaccess for redirecting dynamic URL not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my URL:

```
http://jainpopulationregister.com/page.php?action=about
```

to:

```
http://jainpopulationregister.com/page/action/about/
```

with URL rewriting

My current URL rewrite code is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule page/action/(.*)/ page.php?action=$1
RewriteRule page/action/(.*) page.php?action=$1
```

But when I place this in my root folder, nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are probably missing `RewriteBase   /` and rule like `RewriteRule ^page/action/(.*)/$ /page.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 1):

You want to redirect from
`http://jainpopulationregister.com/page.php?action=about`
to
`http://jainpopulationregister.com/page/action/about/`

but your redirect rule does exactly the opposite. Assuming that you really want to redirect from  `/page.php?action=about` to `/page/action/about/`, use the following configuration in htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page/action/%1/? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page/action/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ pages.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
```

In "pages.php" file get the action `$_GET['action'];`